# Why can't I mine or build on my PocketMine Server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have created a server on my computer for my children to join via their Android devices. I am using [PocketMine-MP](http://pocketmine.net/) to host my server. My children are able to move, access the inventory, kill each other but they are unable to place or mine blocks in any gamemodes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applicable to Pocket Edition, but is the server in adventure mode?

Comment: Are you sure they are not attempting to place or break blocks in the spawn area? In the PC version the spawn area tends to be 'locked down' from changes made to it. Try having your children move away from where they spawn before they attempt to place or break blocks, say,75 blocks away or so in any direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I gave them permissions, per LameBrains, which appears to have worked, so I did not test the spawn area theory...

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do for a private server, is to op everyone so that all of them have admin abilities and none of them will have troubles with permissions.

To op a person on the console:

```
op <user>
```

To op a person in-game:

```
/op <user>
```

The reason there is a slash in front of all commands in-game is so that Minecraft will know if you want to say something or use a commands. If you are still having trouble, make sure that in the settings, the gamemode is set to 0.

```
0 = Survival - You have to find blocks and you have a health bar.
1 = Creative - Has the ability to magically make blocks and fly.
2 = Adventure - Like survival but you can not break or place blocks.
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this helpful, spot on, and rapid reply.  You have made a couple of kids' Saturday a whole lot more fun.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Yes, because it OP is using PocketMine to host the server.

Comment: @r3ronald Remember to press the tick under the votes so other users know that this answer has worked for you.

Answer (score -2):

Enter the commands `/break on`, and `/save-on`

With `/break` you can break blocks, and with `/save-on` you can set blocks.